# "Average processing time of/for/in ..." - which variant is corrent?

Tags: word-choice, prepositions

Which one is correct?

1. Average processing time **of** the largest input data set was X seconds.
2. Average processing time **for** the largest input data set was X seconds.
3. Average processing time **in** the largest input data set was X seconds.

Thanks

Comment: Having a programming background I would choose _for_. (I am not a native, though)

Comment: Each may be grammatically correct with an appropriate sentence, but not necessarily the same sentence in each case. Please edit your question to include the rest of the sentence(s).

Comment: @Lawrence added the rest of the sentence

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are all correct, but may have slightly different *natural* meanings, taking *average* to mean the mathematical *mean* of a set of values:

1. *of* - each element in the set was processed once, and the individual processing times were averaged to produce X;
2. *for* - the whole set was processed repeatedly, and the processing times were averaged to get X; and
3. *in* - the data set consists of a set of numbers representing processing times. The numbers were averaged to get X.